# Sketching solution curves for differential equations

Tags: math, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, maple

I have a few differential equations that I'd like to draw solutions for, for a variety of start values `N_0`

Here are the equations:

```
dN\dt= bN^2 - aN

dN\dt = bN^2 (1 - N\K) - aN
```

How would I go about it?

I don't really care about the language is used. In terms of dedicated math I have mathematica and matlab on my computer. I've got access to maple. I have to do more of this stuff, and I'd like to have examples from any language, as it'll help me figure out which one I want to use and learn it.

Comment: {a, b, N(0)} and {a, b, K, N(0)} are two big parameter spaces. You should specify a region of interest. (For example a==b in the first eq) ...

Answer (score 7):

I'll pretend the first one cannot be solved analytically so as to show how one would go about playing with a general ODE in mathematica.

Define

```
p1[n0_, a_, b_, uplim_: 10] :=(n /. First@NDSolve[
      {n'[t] == b*n[t]^2 - a*n[t], n[0] == n0},n, {t, 0, uplim}]
```

which returns the solution of the ODE, i.e., `a = p1[.1, 2., 3.]` and then e.g. `a[.3]` tells you `n(.3)`. One can then do something like

```
Show[Table[ans = p1[n0, 1, 1];
 Plot[ans[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange \[Rule] Full],
 {n0, 0, 1, .05}], PlotRange \[Rule] {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

which plots a few solutions with different initial values:

[image]

or, to gain some insight into the solutions, one can interactively manipulate the values of `a`, `b` and `n0`:

```
Manipulate[
 ans = p1[n0, a, b];
 Plot[ans[t], {t, 0, 10},PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
 {{n0, .1}, 0, 1},
 {{a, 1}, 0, 2},
 {{b, 1}, 0, 2}]
```

which gives something like

[image]

with the controls active (i.e. you move them and the plot changes; try it live to see what I mean; note that you can set parameters for which the initial conditions gives diverging solutions).

Of course this can be made arbitrarily more complicated. Also in this particular case this ODE is easy enough to integrate analytically, but this numerical approach can be applied to generic ODEs (and many PDEs, too).

Comment: Since `NDSolve` accepts a list of initial conditions, you could also do something like `Plot[(Evaluate[p1[Range[0, 1, .05], 1, 1][t]]), {t, 0, 5}]` to plot a list of solutions in the same graph.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the several good answers, if you just want a quick sketch of an ODE's solutions for many starting values, for guidance, you can always do a one-line `StreamPlot`.  Suppose `a==1` and `b==1`, and `dy/dx == x^2 - x`.

```
StreamPlot[{1, x^2 - x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

`StreamStyle -> "Line"` will give you just lines, no arrows.

Answer (score 0):

In *Mathematica* you use NDSolve (unless it can be solved analytically, in which case you use DSolve.  So for your first equation I tried:

```
b = 1.1; a = 2;
s = NDSolve[{n'[t] == b n[t]^2 - a n[t], n[0] == 1}, n, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[n[t] /. s], {t, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I didn't know what to use for a, b or N0, but I got this result:

[image: Plot of n[t]]

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to solve the equations numerically, `MATLAB` has a set of ODE solvers that might be useful. Check out the documentation for the `ode45` function [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ode23.html).

The general approach is to define an "ode function" that describes the right-hand-side of the differential equations. You then pass this function, along with initial conditions and an integration range to the `ode` solvers.

One attractive feature of this type of approach is that it extends in a straight-forward way to complex systems of coupled ODE's.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, I have the impression that's it's easier to handle *many-variable* ODEs (i.e. systems of ODEs) in Matlab than Mathematica by using vector notation.  For one or few variables, I prefer Mathematica.